# JSON-array and forEach issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, typeerror

So... The problem I have according to the console is:
*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at custom.js:42, at Array.forEach (), at custom.js:39"*

How is "title" undefined? What's wrong with my .forEach? *(sad noises)*

Example of first of six objects in the JSON-array I've built:

```
var  newReleases =  [   
    {
"title":"Honor - Defending the motherland",
"author":"Mark Thomas",
"genre":"Fiction",  
"description":"In legislation and formal documents the suffix shire was generally not used: for example, Bedfordshire was referred to as the administrative county of Bedford and the Northamptonshire council as the county council of Northampton.The 1888 Act did not contain a list of administrative counties: it was not until 1933 and the passing of a new Local Government Act."},
```

For loop with forEach function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    
newReleases.forEach (function (newReleases) { 
    
var bookTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('card-header')
var t = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].title);
bookTitle.appendChild(t);

var bookAuthor = document.getElementsByClassName('card-title')
var a = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].authors);
bookAuthor.appendChild(a);

var cardGenre = document.getElementsByClassName("card-subtitle");
var genre = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].genre);
cardGenre.appendChild(genre);   
    
    
var cardDescr = document.getElementsByClassName('card-text');
var p = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].description);
cardDescr.appendChild(p);
        
    }) //end of forEach
} // end of for-loop
```

Comment: You shouldn't use both `for` and `foreach` to loop over the same array.

Comment: As to why your reference is wrong, it's most likely confusion over the argument passed into the forEach also being named `newReleases`.  That isn't an array.

Comment: Don't use the same variable `newReleases` for the callback function parameter. That makes it the object, not the array.

Comment: Just going off of the logic, it would make more sense if it were say `forEach(function(book){ ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use either `for` or `forEach()`, not both.

```
for (var i = 0; i < newReleases.length; i++) {
  var bookTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('card-header')[0]
  var t = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].title);
  bookTitle.appendChild(t);

  var bookAuthor = document.getElementsByClassName('card-title')[0]
  var a = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].authors);
  bookAuthor.appendChild(a);

  var cardGenre = document.getElementsByClassName("card-subtitle")[0];
  var genre = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].genre);
  cardGenre.appendChild(genre);

  var cardDescr = document.getElementsByClassName('card-text')[0];
  var p = document.createTextNode(newReleases[i].description);
  cardDescr.appendChild(p);
}
```

or

```
newReleases.forEach(function(release) {
  var bookTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('card-header')[0]
  var t = document.createTextNode(release.title);
  bookTitle.appendChild(t);

  var bookAuthor = document.getElementsByClassName('card-title')[0]
  var a = document.createTextNode(release.authors);
  bookAuthor.appendChild(a);

  var cardGenre = document.getElementsByClassName("card-subtitle")[0];
  var genre = document.createTextNode(release.genre);
  cardGenre.appendChild(genre);

  var cardDescr = document.getElementsByClassName('card-text')[0];
  var p = document.createTextNode(release.description);
  cardDescr.appendChild(p);
});
```

When you use `forEach()` you don't need to subscript the array variable, you just use the parameter to the callback function.

Comment: Thanks alot! This is what happens when you teach yourself JS with youtube. hehe! Perhaps you can help me figure out how to get rid of my new shiny error-message ".appendChild is not a function"? From what I can gather from other post here on stack overflow it's an issue with string vs DOM-elements. I just cant figure out where Im going wrong. 
Im using the forEach function like this:

Comment: newReleases.forEach (function (book) { 
  
  var bookTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('card-header');
  var t = document.createTextNode(book.title);
  bookTitle.appendChild(t);

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return. I've updated the answer.